# É possível criar um Widget com varias telas de configuração?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Tenho um **Widget** que tem somente uma tela de configuração mas quero adicionar mais uma como posso fazer isso? Sei que a primeira tela que aparece é uma **Activity**
tento abrir com **Intent** normal mas não funciona.

Fiz este **Intent**:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget_configure_1);

    final SharedPreferences Salvadados = getSharedPreferences(MontWidget, MODE_PRIVATE);

    ListView lista_teste = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_teste);
    String[] dados = new String[]{"xxxx","xxxx","xxxxx"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dados);
    lista_teste.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista_teste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    Intent nextConfig = new Intent(WidgetConfigureActivity.this, Widget_Configure_2.class);
                    startActivity(nextConfig);

                    finish();
                    break;
```

Mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Repare que seu código parece ter um erro de sintaxe, que é a falta do `;` entre as sentenças. Isso foi um erro ao colar aqui ou seu código está realmente assim? Se estiver, esta pode ser a razão.

Comment: Você tem certeza que o nome da outra Activity é Widget_Configure_2 ???

Comment: Sim é o nome da activity que quero chamar

Comment: Bom... aparentemente isso era para funcionar. Pode mostrar o resto do seu código ?

Comment: a próxima linha é um finish para fechar a tela e abrir a proxima

Comment: cara o finish não é para fechar a tela... o finish é para encerrar a aplicação.. Remova-o

Comment: Nao ele fecha a activity  que esta em execução e é no widget a aplicação nem esta aberta ja fiz o teste comentei o finish  e nada aconteceu

Comment: Então faça o que lhe falei... poste seu código inteiro para analise

Comment: pronto postei..

Comment: Verifique nos seus layouts se existe a Activity Widget_Configure_2 criada no XML.

Comment: sim esta criada

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente no seu cóidigo você está setando o `setContentView` para uma outra Activity que não está dentro do seu `Intent`.

O seu:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget_configure_1);`

E você está tentando startar:

`Intent nextConfig = new Intent(WidgetConfigureActivity.this, Widget_Configure_2.class);`

Neste caso o certo seria:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_widget_configure_1);
    Context myContext = this;
    final SharedPreferences Salvadados = getSharedPreferences(MontWidget, MODE_PRIVATE);

    ListView lista_teste = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista_teste);
    String[] dados = new String[]{"xxxx","xxxx","xxxxx"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dados);
    lista_teste.setAdapter(adapter);

    lista_teste.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    Intent nextConfig = new Intent (myContext, Widget_Configure_2.class);
                    startActivity(nextConfig);

                    finish();
                    break;
```

Pois aparentemente você está no layout `activity_widget_configure_1` e não no `WidgetConfigureActivity`. Com isso você não pode iniciar uma outra Activity apartir de outra que ainda nem está iniciada.

Comment: cara isso nao funciona nao  WidgetConfigureActivity.this é o meu contexto de atividade necessariamente tenho que passar.

Comment: Fiz uma pequena edição, tenta fazer o teste

Comment: sem resultado mesma coisa

Comment: Bom... então sugiro dar uma checada nos seus XML's, pois com os parametros passados ele deveria começar a nova Activity.

Comment: tentei chamar outra activity foi de boa ta acontecendo isso  ai mesmo ele nao ta encontrando a tela que é para ser aberta

Comment: Se não tá encontrando, então provavelmente ela não está criada